# Can someone help me installing pyHook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyhook

I have python 3.5 and I can't install pyHook. I tried every method possible. pip, open the cmd directly from the folder, downloaded almost all the pyHook versions. Still can't install it.
 I get this error :'
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirment pyHook.
I have windows 10, 64 bit, 
Can someone help ? Thanks !

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/files/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202087/pyhook-on-python-3-5 this seems like a similar question. Perhaps this can help you out?

Comment: I tried all the possibilities. And I mean .. ALL. Still doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it...

1. Download the py hook module that matches your version of python from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook). Make sure that if you have python 32 bit you download the 32 bit module (even if you have windows 64x) and vice versa.
2. Open your command prompt and navigate to the folder where you downloaded the module
3. Type `pip install` and then the name of the file.

   Ex: `pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-none-win32.whl`

Note : you need pip

**If this does not work please say where and when you got stuck**

Comment: Hey. I tried your method and it didn't work. I keep getting this message.
Requirement "the file name" looks like a filename, but the file does not exist.

Comment: @NarcisBulboaca at what step did you get this message. What where you doing when you get this message. Looking at the error message, did you type the filename correctly and did you navigate to your download folder?

Answer (score 1):

I am really sorry for the dumb question! I installed it now. All i needed to do is to navigate to the folder with the pyHook in it, in CMD. I didn't know how to do it at first, so I jumped this step over, with the tought that it doesn't mean anything. Sorry again and thank you so much for all your responses !