# Unable to install Pyhook Python 3.8.1

Tags: python, pip, pyhook

I'm trying to install `Pyhook` on `Python 3.8.1`via `pip install Pyhook` but I keep receiving this error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyhook (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyhook.
```

I also tried to download it from source and then to install it manually.

```
pip install C:\Users\Andrea\Downloads\pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl



ERROR: pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Maybe it's not compatible with `Python3.8` since the last versione is `cp37`.

Could I install it in any way? Or I just need to use `Python 3.7`?

Comment: Doesn't work for 3.7 either and I encounter the same error. Don't bother to downgrade the version of Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing the below steps:

- Download the py hook module that matches your version of python from here. Make sure that if you have python 32 bit you download the 32 bit module (even if you have windows 64x) and vice versa.
- Open your command prompt and navigate to the folder where you downloaded the module
- Type pip install and then the name of the file.

Ex: `pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-none-win32.whl`

Reference for the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39876454/can-someone-help-me-installing-pyhook)

Comment: Alredy tried, these are both the command and the output: pip install C:\Users\Andrea\Downloads\pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl ERROR: pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Answer (score 1):

The file `pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` which you have downloaded is only compatible with `cp37`, i.e. python **3.7**, since you are using 3.8, this will not work.

Checking [this site of whl file](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook), there are also none for python 3.7, but there is a fork of `pyhook` called `PyWinHook`, for which the fitting `whl` is [available](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywinhook)

Note that you can always run in your cmd `python -c "import wheel.pep425tags as w; print(w.get_supported())"` to find which version of `whl` files are supported

Answer (score 0):

Just check if python 3.7 is already installed in your system. If yes, then you can use it to install the 3.7 whl using the below command

py -3.7 -m pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

you have to then launch the program from 3.7

py -3.7 program.py

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pyHook install:

```
pip install pyWinhook
```

and in your program use the import:

```
import pyWinhook as pyHook
```