# import pyHook. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyHook'

Tags: python, python-3.8

I am using `Python3.8.0`, my PC is **x64 bit** and my code starts as :

`import pyHook`

*When I run the program,
it shows :*

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "abc.py", line 1, in
>
> import pyHook
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyHook'

**I have already installed Pyhook and I have verified it in cmd by writing the following code**

`python -m pip install pyWinhook-1.6.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`

**Output :**

*Requirement already satisfied*

I visited these links, but it did not helped:
[Getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyHook'" even with module installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308559/getting-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyhook-even-with-module-install)

This link
[PyHook on python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202087/pyhook-on-python-3-5)
says that *I should Install pyhook32 even if I have 64bit. I tried that and cmd does'nt allow system to install that.*

Anyone have any other idea ? Please help me if I am doing anything wrong :-(

Comment: Have you tried `import pyWinhook` as that is what you have installed?

Comment: I have another problem. I am trying to design a keylogger.

I referred this site :

[link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-a-keylogger-in-python/)

I do not know which lines should I change. I have `x64 bit OS`

Copying this code causes a lot of Errors. Can you help me out please

Comment: This should be a new question. Please create one with the appropriate tags. You add a link in the comments here if you want, then I can take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `pip3 install pynput` in cmd

Now in your python code, remove `import pyHook` and write `import pynput`

Both works same